# Python multiprocessing result does not save on disk

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
def get_rstname_links(pref_urls, pref_name):
    rstname_links = []

    for link in tqdm.tqdm(pref_urls):
        HEADERS = {"User-Agent": random.choice(AGENT_LIST)}
        
        try:
            html_content = requests.get(
                link, proxies=proxies, headers=HEADERS, timeout=100, verify=False
            ).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
            hyperlinks = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rstname"})
            for hyperlink in hyperlinks:
                links = hyperlink.find_all("a")
                for link in links:
                    href = link.get("href")
                    print(href)
                    rstname_links.append(href)
        except:
            pass

   
    with open(f"{ABSOLUTE_PATH}output/urls/{pref_name}.txt", "w") as f:
        for link in rstname_links:
            f.write("https://example.com" + link + "\n")
    print(f"{pref_name} URL EXTRACTION DONE!")
```

multiprocessing code:

```
    chunk_size = math.ceil(len(pref_urls) / (mp.cpu_count() * 20))

    range_of_chunk = list(
        chunks(range(0, len(pref_urls)), chunk_size)
    )
    processes = []
    for chunk in range_of_chunk:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=get_rstname_links,
            args=(
                pref_urls[chunk[0] : chunk[-1]],
                pref_name,
            ),
        )
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()
    for idx, proc in enumerate(processes):
        proc.join()
```

Here, after all the processes completed the files are supposed to write on disk as per the code in the first function, but it's not saving on the disk.
Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually solved the problem like this:

```
def get_rstname_links(pref_urls):
    rstname_links = []
    for link in tqdm.tqdm(pref_urls):
        HEADERS = {"User-Agent": random.choice(AGENT_LIST)}

        try:
            html_content = requests.get(
                link, proxies=proxies, headers=HEADERS, timeout=100, verify=False
            ).text
            # parse the html content
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
            # get all the hyperlinks in the html content list <li>
            hyperlinks = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rstname"})
            for hyperlink in hyperlinks:
                links = hyperlink.find_all("a")
                for link in links:
                    href = link.get("href")
                    print(href)
                    rstname_links.append(href)
        except:
            pass

    return rstname_links
```

changed multiprocessing code:

```
def url_download(pref_name):
    # parse the arguments
    base_links = get_hyperlinks(f"https://example.com/{pref_name}/")

    pref_urls = visit_links(base_links)
    # rstname_links = get_rstname_links(pref_urls)
    pool = Pool(mp.cpu_count() * 50)
    rstname_links = list(
        tqdm.tqdm(
            pool.imap(get_rstname_links, chunks(pref_urls, 100)),
            total=math.ceil(len(pref_urls) / 100),
        )
    )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    rstname_links = [item for sublist in rstname_links for item in sublist]
    print(f"{pref_name} : {len(rstname_links)}")
    return rstname_links
```

Then, in the main method, write the `rstname_links` data on the disk.